# NVD3 Line Chart Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the NVD3 library to make simple line charts based on data generated in a Rails controller. The code I'm using to generate data in Rails is:

```
task.task_values.each do |u|
 array.push({ :x => u.created_at.to_i * 1000, :y => u.value.to_i })
end
data_label = task.name + " ("+ task_unit +")"
taskValuesList = [{:key => data_label, :values => array}]
data = {:type => "line", :data => taskValuesList}
```

Then, in my view, I have the following JS code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

chart.xAxis
   .showMaxMin(false)
       .tickFormat(function(d){return d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y")(new Date(d));});
chart.yAxis
   .tickFormat(d3.format(',d'));

d3.select('#chart<%= i %> svg')
  .datum(data.data)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
});
```

The chart renders properly, but when I try to mouseover data points to show the tooltip, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

Comment: Can you update your question with the data that is been passed to the chart.

Comment: Here's some sample data: [{:key=>"Blood Pressure Diastolic (mmHg)", :values=>[{:x=>1373403179000, :y=>91}, {:x=>1373403469000, :y=>95}, {:x=>1373403567000, :y=>61}, {:x=>1373404123000, :y=>56}, {:x=>1373404515000, :y=>56}, {:x=>1373404592000, :y=>56}, {:x=>1373404749000, :y=>56}, {:x=>1373405085000, :y=>56}]}]

Comment: I have no idea about ruby-on-rails but Is the data passed a JSON object?

Comment: Did you investigate with your browser's javascript console/debugger ? (to see where the code fails, what exactly is being passed to nvd3)

Comment: Through the Chrome JS console, I get the following error trace but not a specific line where the code is failing - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
(anonymous function)
showTooltip
(anonymous function)
event
(anonymous function)
event
pointPaths.on.on.on.series
(anonymous function)"

Comment: I'm having the same issue, couldn't find a solution yet, but I've found that avoiding zeros in values sometime helps. Using `.useInteractiveGuideline(true)` on the chart works consistently for me.

Comment: I had the same error and got stuck for hours. Similar to @jjmontes I found out that avoiding only zeroes values (or equal values) helps. In fact, by adding some random noise on the data the chart worked fine. I guess it is a bug in nvd3.

Comment: I had the same issue when using `Date Objects` as x values. Using unix timestamp instead solved the problem since the value has to be a number.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same error and got stuck for hours. After some investigation I found out that I was using the most recent version of **d3.js** which was not compatible to the most recent version of **nvd3.js**

Make sure that you are using the d3.js version that is included in the nvd3 repository: [/lib/d3.v3.js](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/lib/d3.v3.js)

That was quite tricky to find out. In particular because the [nvd3 documentation](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/2.-Getting-Started) tells you to use the latest d3.js version ;-(

Comment: One detail, this can be repro on a line chart containing two lines sharing a common (x,y) point.

Answer (score 4):

If you are seeing a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` it is possibly because your data series contain different numbers of points.

Check if this happens with only one series.

Comment: Thanks -- I am seeing this.

Comment: I just ran into this problem for my Y axis as well... looking into making sure that everything matches up to avoid this error

Comment: This is the cause. All bar groups must have the same number of elements.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your data is in JSON format,

Here is how the sample JSON data should look like

```
data = [{
    key : "Line 1",
    color : "#51A351",
    values : [{
        x : 1373403179000,
        y : 40
    }, {
        x : 1373403469000,
        y : 30
    }, {
        x : 1373403567000,
        y : 20
    }]
}, {
    key : "Line 2",
    color : "#BD362F",
    values : [{
        x : 1373403179000,
        y : 60
    }, {
        x : 1373403469000,
        y : 50
    }, {
        x : 1373403567000,
        y : 70
    }]
}]
```

**`UPDATE :`**
Here is a working fiddle of a [NVD3 Line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/gxb6r/)

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the data as a JSON object. An example of the parameters being received by the JS code is: {"type":"line","data":[{"key":"Blood Pressure Diastolic (mmHg)","values":[{"x":1373403179000,"y":91},{"x":1373403469000,"y":95},{"x":1373403567000,"y":61},{"x":1373404123000,"y":56},{"x":1373404515000,"y":56},{"x":1373404592000,"y":56},{"x":1373404749000,"y":56},{"x":1373405085000,"y":56}]}]}

Comment: In addition, the plot appears fine but the error comes when I mouseover for a tooltip

Comment: As I mentioned, the data is in JSON format but I'm still getting the error - would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same error when I try to click the series names in the legend to temp. hide them.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to a working version of the LineChart in a fiddle. Have a look and see where you have gone wrong in your code.

Comment: unable to see chart in the fiddle