# d3.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have been getting stuck on 2 errors that I have been unable to figure out...I am trying to build a Scatter Plot out of some backend data. The BackEnd sends me a Javascript object (tabularData) with the information I need and I use it to create a graph.
I am using ExtJS 4.2.2 and the most modern versions of d3.js and nv.d3.js

The first error is a uncaught typeerror that seems to complain about nv.d3.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined nv.d3.js:11193
(anonymous function) nv.d3.js:11193
attrFunction d3.js:597
(anonymous function) d3.js:884
d3_selection_each d3.js:890
d3_selectionPrototype.each d3.js:883
d3_selectionPrototype.attr d3.js:580
updateInteractiveLayer nv.d3.js:11192
```

The second error is an error that has to do with d3.js

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,5)" d3.js:591
attrConstant d3.js:591
(anonymous function) d3.js:884
d3_selection_each d3.js:890
d3_selectionPrototype.each d3.js:883
d3_selectionPrototype.attr d3.js:580
(anonymous function) nv.d3.js:5010
(anonymous function) d3.js:884
d3_selection_each d3.js:890
d3_selectionPrototype.each d3.js:883
chart nv.d3.js:4872
d3_selectionPrototype.call d3.js:897
(anonymous function) nv.d3.js:11818
(anonymous function) d3.js:8562
d3_selection_each d3.js:890
d3_transitionPrototype.each d3.js:8560
chart nv.d3.js:11729
d3_selectionPrototype.call d3.js:897
chart.update nv.d3.js:11738
window.onresize nv.d3.js:904
window.onresiz
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with d3.select, but it doesn't make sense that it is failing because buildData creates a legitimate Object. I also thought it might be because a lot of my x values and y values are the same, but using the [live code scatter plot example](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html) on nvd3.org shows me this is not the reason.

Here is my actual code for reference...

```
 buildScatterPlot: function buildScatterPlot(tabularData){
     Ext.vcops.chrome.D3js.load(function() {
        Ext.vcops.chrome.nvd3.load(function(){

            nv.addGraph(function() {
                var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                    .showDistX(false)    //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
                    .showDistY(false)
                    .transitionDuration(350)
                    .color(d3.scale.category20().range());

                //Configure how the tooltip looks.
                chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
                    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
                });

                //Axis settings
                var xAxisLabel = tabularData.columns[1].label;
                var yAxisLabel = tabularData.columns[2].label;
                var xFormat;
                var yFormat;
                var xUnitId = tabularData.columns[1].unit === null ? null : tabularData.columns[1].unit.unitId;
                var yUnitId = tabularData.columns[2].unit === null ? null : tabularData.columns[2].unit.unitId;
                switch(xUnitId){
                    case "percent":
                        xFormat = '.02%'
                        break;
                    case null:
                    default:
                        xFormat = 'd'
                        break;
                }
                switch(yUnitId){
                    case "percent":
                        yFormat = '.02%';
                        break;
                    case null:
                    default:
                        yFormat = 'd';
                        break;
                }
                chart.xAxis
                    .axisLabel(xAxisLabel)
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(xFormat));
                chart.yAxis
                    .axisLabel(yAxisLabel)
                    .tickFormat(d3.format(yFormat));

                var d3data = buildData(xUnitId, yUnitId);
                console.log(d3data);
                d3.select('#chart svg')
                    .datum(d3data)
                    .call(chart);
                nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                return chart;
            });

            /**************************************
             * Data generator
             */
            function buildData(xUnitId, yUnitId) { //# groups,# points per group
                var data = [];
                var skipped = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < tabularData.totalRowCount; i++) {
                    var xVal;
                    var yVal;
                    if(tabularData.rows[i].cells[2].renderedValue === "-"){
                        skipped++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    switch(xUnitId){
                        case "percent":
                            xVal = tabularData.rows[i].cells[1].value / 100.0;
                            break;
                        case null:
                            xVal = tabularData.rows[i].cells[1].value;
                            break;
                    }
                    if(tabularData.rows[i].cells[2].renderedValue === "-"){
                        skipped++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    switch(yUnitId){
                        case "percent":
                            yVal = tabularData.rows[i].cells[2].value / 100.0;
                            break;
                        case null:
                            yVal = tabularData.rows[i].cells[2].value;
                            break;
                    }
                    if(xVal === null || yVal === null){
                        continue;
                    }
                    console.log(xVal);
                    console.log(yVal);
                    data.push({
                        key: tabularData.rows[i].objectIdentifier.resourceKey.resourceName,
                        values: []
                    });
                    data[i-skipped].values.push({
                        x: xVal,
                        y: yVal,
                        size: Math.random()  //Configure the size of each scatter point
                    });
                }
                return data;
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my issue, this turned out to be an incompatibility with d3.v3. I was using d3.v3, but the stable release of nvd3 uses d3.v2: 
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/7e9b8c013c4d8e8ad5775062c438c842bc112585

I solved this by including the d3.v2 version that is provided in nvd3/lib:
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/lib/d3.v2.min.js

Found answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994982/469594

Comment: This may be the answer...
    nv.version = '1.1.15b';
var d3 = {
    version: "3.4.8"
  };

Comment: nvd3 uses d3 version 3.1.5, but i did not see 3.4.8

Comment: I have confirmed that this is truly the error. Thank you for your help!